# Why does the equation $x^4 -17 = 2y^2$ have no rational solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am interested in understanding why $x^4 - 17 = 2 y^2$ has no rational solutions.

My first approach was to show that every rational solution leads to an integral solution but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688325/587142

Comment: I don't think that this question should be tagged with tag "elementary-number-theory" since it only contains linear Diophantine equations. Tag "number-theory" may be suitable.